# how kurtosis is calculated in scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy

I have this code to calculate kurtosis (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Kurtosis.html) using my own code and I compare it to `scipy.stats.kurtosis`

```
a = array([   1. ,    2. ,    2.5,  400. ,    6. ,    0. ])
#kurtosis (gives: 4.19886)
print (sum((a - np.mean(a)) ** 4)/len(a)) / np.std(a)**4
# scipy kurtosis (gives: 5.996677)
print scipy.stats.kurtosis(a,bias=False)
```

why is scipy giving a different result? I followed the definition in mathworld.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kurtosis.html#scipy.stats.kurtosis) of scipy's kurtosis function, scipy is calculting Excess Kurtosis by default (with the minus 3):

> scipy.stats.kurtosis(a, axis=0, fisher=True, bias=True)
>
> Computes the kurtosis (Fisher or Pearson) of a dataset.
>
> Kurtosis is the fourth central moment divided by the square of the
>   variance. If Fisher’s definition is used, then 3.0 is subtracted from
>   the result to give 0.0 for a normal distribution.
>
> If bias is False then the kurtosis is calculated using k statistics to
>   eliminate bias coming from biased moment estimators

Setting `fisher` to `False` will give you what you expected:

```
In [1]: a = np.array([   1. ,    2. ,    2.5,  400. ,    6. ,    0. ])

In [2]: scipy.stats.kurtosis(a, fisher=False)
Out[2]: 4.198860780044809
```

Comment: highly counterintuitive - why doesn't ``scipy.stats.kurtosis(a, fisher=False,bias=False)`` give the same answer as my code? My code does no bias correction

Comment: Apparently the interpretation of the `bias` parameter is confusing. Setting `bias=False` WILL do bias correction, not the other way round.